# Scanning files in directories and subdirectories

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Essentially what I'm looking to do is search the files within a folder structure for a list of invoices that are provided and copy the desired data over to a new file. My below script works as described, however the script chokes on search folders that contain sub directories. I need to modify the script to scan the root folder and it's sub directories files. Any idea what to do, I've tried several different code updates but non seem to work:

```
import tkinter
import os
import fnmatch
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
from pathlib import Path

#filedialog  

content = ''
BrowsePath = ''
SearchPath = ''

top = tkinter.Tk()

#********************************************************FIELDS****************************************************************************
#Browse entry field
Browse1 = Label(text="Search List:").grid(row=0)

BrowsePath = StringVar()
BrowsePath.set("Select File Containing Invoice Numbers")
BrowseL = Label(bd=5,textvariable=BrowsePath, width=100,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0,column=1)



#Search Folder
Searce1 = Label( text="Search Folder:").grid(row=1)

SearchPath = StringVar()
SearchPath.set("Select Folder to Search")
SearchL = Label(bd=5,textvariable=SearchPath, width=100,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1,column=1)



#OutputFile
OutputL1 = Label( text="Output File:").grid(row=2)

OutputPath = StringVar()
OutputPath.set("File to Save Results to")
OutputL2 = Label(bd=5,textvariable=OutputPath, width=100,relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=2,column=1)


#********************************************************FUNCTIONS****************************************************************************

#Process complete function
def GetCallBack():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Find Invoices", "Processing complete!")


#********************************************************FILE PICKERS****************************************************************************

    #Select file containing list of invoices
def GetFile():
    global content
    global BrowsePath
    filename = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    content = infile.read()
    BrowsePath.set(os.path.realpath(filename))
    return content

    #Select directory containing invoice files
def SearchDir():
    global content
    global SearchPath
    pathname = askdirectory()
    SearchPath.set(os.path.realpath(pathname))
    return content


    #Creates the save file with isolated invoices
def SaveFile():

    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),"Results.txt"))

    OutputPath.set(filename) #update label with location of file




#********************************************************READING invoice LIST FILE****************************************************************************


def  GetPOCount():
    PO = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.realpath(BrowsePath.get()))] #isolates list of invoices
    ponum_count = sum(1 for line in open(os.path.realpath(BrowsePath.get()))) #gets count of invoice numbers
    return PO, ponum_count #can be indexed


def GetFileNames():
    files = os.listdir(SearchPath.get()) #gets list of files
    return files #can be indexed

def GetFileLineCount():
    files = GetFileNames()
    file_count = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(SearchPath.get()),'*.*'))
    line_count = sum(1 for line in open(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),files[file_count-1])))) #gets count of lines in invoice file
    return line_count, file_count

def FindPOs():
    po_number = GetPOCount()[0]
    po_counter = GetPOCount()[1]

    print(po_number)
    print(po_counter)


    file_counter = GetFileLineCount()[1] 
    file_name = GetFileNames()

    print(file_name)
    print(file_counter)


    # For each file
    for filename in file_name:
        print("Searching " + filename)

        with open(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),filename),'r') as content_file:
            line_count = sum(1 for line in content_file) #gets count of lines in invoice file
            print(line_count)
            po_line = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),filename)))] #isolates each line
            result_filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(SearchPath.get()),"Results.txt"))
            OutputPath.set(result_filename)
            log = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(SearchPath.get()),"FoundInvoices.txt"))

            # For each line in file
            #TODO: make this for each po_line
            for PONum in po_number:
                print("looking for " + PONum)

                for line in range (0,line_count):

                    #locate Header Record
                    if po_line[line][16:18] == "10" or po_line[line][15:17] == "10":
                        print("On a header record")

                        if PONum in po_line[line].strip():
                            print("Looking for " + PONum)
                            # Write the current line to the results file
                            with open(result_filename,'a+') as file:
                                file.write(po_line[line] + '\n')

                            # Write this PONum to the log file
                            with open(log,'a+') as logs:
                                logs.write(PONum + '\n')

                            # Loop from the next line to the end
                            with open(result_filename,'a+') as file:
                                for z in range (line+1,line_count):
                                    if ((po_line[z][16:18] != "10") and (po_line[z] != '\n') and (po_line[z][15:17] != "10") and (po_line[z][16:18] != "05")):
                                        file.write(po_line[z] + '\n')
                                    else:
                                    # Once we've found a "10" or newline, stop printing this PO
                                        break


    GetCallBack()







#********************************************************BUTTONS****************************************************************************

# Search List Browse Button logic
BrowseButton = tkinter.Button(text ="Browse", command = GetFile).grid(row=0,column = 2)

# Search Directory Button logic
SearchButton = tkinter.Button(text ="Search", command = SearchDir).grid(row=1,column = 2)

# Find POs Button Logic
FindButton = tkinter.Button( text ="Get Invoices", command = FindPOs).grid(row=4,column = 1)


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked at os.walk()?

Comment: I did, the issue was it wasn't working when trying to refer back to the files that it spit out. Essentially they weren't index-able.

Comment: You should definitely be using `os.walk()`. If you weren't able to get it working, maybe include in your question and example of what you tried?

Comment: The issue is with os.walk() when I try to call it in a later function it spits out individual file name characters rather than the complete list of file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code is a bit overly complex. Perhaps this is only a portion of the total code. For instance GetFileLineCount() returns two variables, but one of them is never used in your code. GetFileNames() could produce the same result.

```
def GetFileNames():
    files = os.listdir(SearchPath.get()) #gets list of files
    file_count = len(fnmatch.filter(files),'*.*'))
    return files, file_count #can be indexed
```

Or better yet you could replace GetFileNames with an os.walk() function:

```
def GetFileNames():
    filepaths = []
    for root,dir,files in os.walk(SearchPath.get()):
        if len(files) > 0:
            for file in files:
                filepaths.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    return filepaths
```

This will give you a list of all of the files in your SearchPath. Then you can use the same loop but not have to join your SearchPath with your filename each time:

```
for filename in filepaths:
        print("Searching " + filename)

        with open(filename,'r') as content_file:
            line_count = sum(1 for line in content_file)
```

... and so on.

**Note** - I haven't rewritten all of your code for you. You will likely need to make some modifications here and there to make this work, but this should provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: That is the entirety of the code, I'm very new to python. This was in response to having to dig up a couple hundred files, it worked great for the single folder structure, but figured I should re-work it to work with sub-directories as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. Welcome to StackOverflow.